# QT debug error r6010 abort has been called while running perfectly

Tags: c++, qt, abort, qwt

I am trying to generate QWTspectrogram using a file. there are 500 binary files to show an annimation with a slider in UI. the program works fine but sometimes it gives "debug error r6010 abort has been called" error and crashes on any random occasion I have no idea why this shows up because it is random however it depends on the change in fnum as slider moves but not at any fixed value or time(it does not appear at stationary condition). below is the code for my program

setAlpha is changed with the change in slider of UI.

```
void Plot::setAlpha( int alpha )
{
    fnum=alpha;
    d_spectrogram->setData( new mydata(fnum,dial) );
    d_spectrogram->attach( this );
    replot();
}

class mydata: public QwtRasterData
{
    typedef signed short int sBYTE;
    char filepath[35]; 
    sBYTE *fileBuf;    
    FILE *file = NULL; 
public:

    mydata(int fnum, int dial)
    {
        setInterval( Qt::XAxis, QwtInterval( 0, (area)-1 ) );
        setInterval( Qt::YAxis, QwtInterval( 0, (area)-1 ) );
        setInterval( Qt::ZAxis, QwtInterval( -dial, dial ) );

        {
            sprintf_s(filepath, "c:/mydata/uwpi%d.bin", fnum);
            fopen_s(&file,filepath, "rb");
            long fileSize = getFileSizex(file);
            fileBuf = new sBYTE[fileSize];
            fread(fileBuf, fileSize, 1, file);
            fclose(file);
        }
    }

    virtual double value( double x, double y ) const
    {

        int x_pos = static_cast<int>(x);
        int y_pos = static_cast<int>(y);
        const double c =  (fileBuf[ ((x_pos)+((area-y_pos)*area))]);
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: `the program works fine but sometimes it gives "...abort has been called" error and crashes`. Then the program is not fine. You are accessing fileBuf without checking whether or not `((x_pos)+((area-y_pos)*area))` is a valid index.

Comment: no mean it shows all frames when I move the slider till end but sometime abort() error appears in a random fashion. it showed ftell error when file was not loaded properly previously.

Comment: @user3871970 are this files very big? How much RAM you have on this computer?

Comment: 4Gb RAM  and files are 529kb each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by using QFile, QDatasteam and QVector

thanks for your response it worked now…

```
QFile myfile;
myfile.setFileName(“c:/file.bin”);
if(!myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) return;
QDataStream data(&myfile);
data.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
QVector<qint16> result;
while(!data.atEnd()) { qint16 x; data >> x; result.append(x);
}
```